# Blogger: JavaScript for image thumbnail?

Tags: javascript, blogger, blogspot

In Blogger, my image thumbnails are cropped and not showing the original image.

### How do I show a thumbnail of the uncropped original image?

My blog: [ravitejasps.blogspot.in](http://ravitejasps.blogspot.in/)

Screenshot of the original image on my blog post:
[image: This is the original image on my blog.]

Screenshot of the cropped image on the homepage:
[image: On home page it is showing cropped image]

Snippets used to create thumbnail:

HTML:

```
<a expr:href='data:post.url'>
    <div class='img-thumbnail'>
        <span class='overlay' />
        <script type='text/javascript'>
           document.write(bp_thumbnail_resize(&quot;<data:post.thumbnailUrl/>&quotenter code here;,&#39;<data:post.title/>&#39;));
        </script>
    </div>
</a>
```

JavaScript:

```
function bp_thumbnail_resize(image_url,post_title)
{
    var image_width=200;
    var image_height=160;
    image_tag='<img width="'+image_width+'" height="'+image_height+'" src="'+image_url.replace('/s72-c/','/w'+image_width+'-h'+image_height+'-c/')+'" alt="'+post_title.replace(/"/g,"")+'" title="'+post_title.replace(/"/g,"")+'"/>';
    if(post_title!="") return image_tag; else return ""; 
}
```

Comment: Did my answer help you? If so, …[What should I do when someone answers my question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) ;)

Answer (score 1):

### Images are cropped by default, but that can be changed

By default, Blogger automatically crops thumbnails to a 72-pixel square. In the snippet you have posted, you may change this in the `.replace(…)` statement by removing `-c` from the replacement string:

So, this…

```
image_url.replace('/s72-c/','/w'+image_width+'-h'+image_height+'-c/')
                                                                ^^
```

…becomes this…

```
image_url.replace('/s72-c/','/w'+image_width+'-h'+image_height+'/')
```

In this scenario, the image will be restricted to the smaller of the two dimensions.

Alternatively, you can just change your replacement snippet to simply use a single "size" (this works like max-size) while removing the `-c`:

```
image_url.replace('/s72-c/','/s200/')
```

For more examples of ways you can configure the size and cropping of thumbnails, see: [Resize the Default Resolution of Thumbnails in Blogger | mybloggertricks.com](http://www.mybloggertricks.com/2015/11/resize-blogspot-thumbnails-resolution.html)